# Trace of $I+A+A^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace

$a=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$
$$A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & a &a^2 &a^3 & a^4 \\ 0 & a &a^2 &a^3 & a^4\\ 0 & 0 &a^2 &a^3 & a^4\\ 0 & 0 &0 &a^3 & a^4\\ 0 & 0 &0 &0 & a^4 \end{bmatrix}$$

find trace of $I+A+A^2$

I wrote $$A=a^{10}\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1 &1 &1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 &1 &1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &1 &1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &0 &1 & 1\\ 0 & 0 &0 &0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
since $a^{10}=1$, so $I+A+A^2$could be found by simple matrix multiplication and addition of A. andd then trace came to be 15,which is wrong.what are other possibilities?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your transformation is not allowed. This works for determinants, not for matrices. Your second equation is wrong. You changed the matrix by manipulating individual columns (which you can see because the trace changed).

You don't need to square the matrix. Just calculate the *diagonal* terms of $A^2$. You will see that for a triangular matrix this is a trivial operation (hint: what's above the diagonal doesn't matter at all).

Comment: diagnol elements in $A^2$ get squared.then they are added to those in A and also a 1 is added to each due to I. is that right?

Comment: Exactly. And because $a^5=1$, you have $(a^3)^2=a$ and $(a^4)^2=a^3$, so you have again $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4$. And this sum is equal to $0$ because these are precisely all fifth roots of $1$ in the complex plane (symmetrically positioned around the origin).

Comment: thank you orion. but what did you mean when you said "You changed the trace of the matrix." in your answer above?

Comment: The trace of the first matrix up there is $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4$. The trace of the second is $5a^{10}$. I mentioned it because this should have reminded you that you did something illegal (when $\operatorname{Tr} A\neq \operatorname{Tr} A$ something is wrong).

Comment: i really screwed up everything in this problem. thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Note that $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4=0$. So $\text{Tr}(A)=0$. The diagonal of $A^2$ consists of $1, a^2, a^4, a^6=a, a^8=a^3$. So $\text{Tr}(A^2)=0$ too. Then $\text{Tr}(I+A+A^2)=\text{Tr}(I)=5$.

Comment: One term too many. $1+a+a^2+a^3+a^4=0$ (five roots). The $a^5=1$ is extra.

Comment: Of course. Thanks! :)

Comment: thank you sir martin, very neatly explained.

Comment: You are welcome!